# Nodejs on Appengine, google-cloud/storage: How to check if a folder exists and if yes, get the all the files from it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, nodes, gcloud

I'm having a hard time translating from Node.js to Appengine @google-cloud/storage.
To verify if a folder is up-to-date I go through some simple steps:

1. check if folder exist. If not, return false, if yes ->
2. check the files if they have the right name

In regular javascript, goes like this and works without problems:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(full_path)) {
    return false;
}
else {
    // else verify if all requiered files exist
    let check = true;
    let files = fs.readdirSync(full_path);
    allExpectedFiles.forEach((f) => {
        if (pfs.pfs.getFileName('pictures') !== f && files.indexOf(f) === -1) {
            // console.log(c.cyan, 'Not found file: ' + f);
            check = false;
        }
    });
    return check;
}
```

Using @google-cloud/storage library... I just can't make it work.

I tried:

```
// if folder does not exist:
const dir = bucket.file(full_path);
let doesExist = await dir.exists();
console.info('For:', name, ' does folder exist?:',full_path, doesExist[0]);

if (!doesExist[0]) {
    // folder does not exist so it's not uptodate
    return false;
}
```

I got false even for thous who do exist.

Note 1: If I check with a file (adding the file name instead of ending in "/"), it works. But I need to check the folder.

Also, I tried to get the files from the folder (forcing true for folders by checking for file) and I can't get them either.

```
        let files = await bucket.getFiles({prefix: full_path, delimiter:'.json'});
    console.log(c.magenta,'Here are the files:');
    console.log(files);
```

I got nothing. I played with prefix and delimiter but I just can't get them to work.

Note 2: I did read: [How subdirectories works](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork), but... obviously I can't get it.

Any suggestions? I'm aware that this should be a very simple task, I just can't make it work.

**Later edit:**
I manage to get the files but only as "all/the/long/path/filename.json". I can live with it, I'll extract the file name but it seems something is wrong, it can't be that difficult. Here is my code:

```
let files = await bucket.getFiles({
        prefix   : full_path
    });
    files = files[0];
    files.forEach((f)=>{
        console.log(c.magenta, 'Fisierele cele multe:', f.name);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really are no directories in the Cloud Storage. They're just emulated based on the file paths.

So just skip the steps for checking if the destination directory exists and creating it and just go directly to checking the files in the "directory", building their file paths based on the source directory that you want to check.

Comment: Salut Dan si multumesc de reply.
I already did it but in my app I have several hundred of thousands files, organized by folders. I implemented an "erase all" and without folders, it took 6 sec to delete about half of them. I was doing this in no-time by simply deleting a folder in regular storage. I was hoping I'm missing something.

Comment: In Cloud storage you have to delete each file independently, the traditional filesystem directory removal doesn't apply because the directories themselves do not exist.

Comment: And so I did. Only to notice that the speed is pretty slow. It takes about 4-5 seconds to delete 600 +/- files. And about 20ms to read them (very small - 10-20k jsons).